# ngIf show/hide elements and also execute function

Tags: angular

I have some example

```
  <div *ngIf="nameOfDocx == 'emailTab'" class="tabcontent" #tab2 label="Email">
    <details *ngFor="let doc of emaildocuments">
      <summary>{{doc.documentGuid}}</summary>
      <ul *ngFor="let page of doc.DocumentPages">
        <li (click)="pickDoc(page)">{{ page.pageGuid}}</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
```

it's work fine display and hide DOM elements but i also 
at the same time execute some function when varialble equals string. It is possible ? For example some function that add element to DOM when ngIf is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add any expression in your `*ngIf`, like a method. Do your logic in the method.

```
  <div *ngIf="myMethod(nameOfDocx)" class="tabcontent" #tab2 label="Email">
    <details *ngFor="let doc of emaildocuments">
      <summary>{{doc.documentGuid}}</summary>
      <ul *ngFor="let page of doc.DocumentPages">
        <li (click)="pickDoc(page)">{{ page.pageGuid}}</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
```

Then in your component class create a method, with your logic:

```
myMethod(nameOfDocx){
   // some logic
   return nameOfDocx == 'emailTab'
}
```

Comment: Lol you beat me to it, exact same answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Call your method like this : `{{yourMethod()}}`

```
 <div *ngIf="nameOfDocx == 'emailTab'" class="tabcontent" #tab2 label="Email">
   {{yourMethod()}}
   <details *ngFor="let doc of emaildocuments">
      <summary>{{doc.documentGuid}}</summary>
      <ul *ngFor="let page of doc.DocumentPages">
        <li (click)="pickDoc(page)">{{ page.pageGuid}}</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
```

Comment: it's fine but i wonder why this method 
is execute as many times as the number of elements in loop for

Comment: yes because it's called in every iteration , this is the only solution if you want to call it from the template , otherwise you can create a method , inside it , call `yourMethod` and return the comparison `nameOfDocx == 'emailTab'`